# Removing elements in a functional style

Tags: algorithm, f#

I have been struggling with something that looks like a simple algorithm, but can't find a clean way to express it in a functional style so far. Here is an outline of the problem: suppose I have 2 arrays X and Y,

```
X = [| 1; 2; 2; 3; 3 |]
Y = [| 5; 4; 4; 3; 2; 2 |]
```

What I want is to retrieve the elements that match, and the unmatched elements, like:

```
matched = [| 2; 2; 3 |]
unmatched = [| 1; 3 |], [| 4; 4; 5 |]
```

In pseudo-code, this is how I would think of approaching the problem:

```
let rec match matches x y =
    let m = find first match from x in y
    if no match, (matches, x, y)
    else
        let x' = remove m from x
        let y' = remove m from y
        let matches' = add m to matches
        match matches' x' y'
```

The problem I run into is the `"remove m from x"` part - I can't find a clean way to do this (I have working code, but it's ugly as hell). Is there a nice, idiomatic functional way to approach that problem, either the removal part, or a different way to write the algorithm itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be solved easily using the right data structures, but in case you wanted to do it manually, here's how I would do it in Haskell. I don't know F# well enough to translate this, but I hope it is similar enough. So, here goes, in (semi-)literate Haskell.

```hs
overlap xs ys =
```

I start by sorting the two sequences to get away from the problem of having to know about previous values.

```hs
  go (sort xs) (sort ys)
    where
```

The two base cases for the recursion are easy enough to handle -- if either list is empty, the result includes the other list in the list of elements that are *not* overlapping.

```hs
      go xs []           = ([], (xs, []))
      go [] ys           = ([], ([], ys))
```

I then inspect the first elements in each list. If they match, I can be sure that the lists overlap on that element, so I add that to the included elements, and I let the excluded elements be. I continue the search for the rest of the list by recursing on the tails of the lists.

```hs
      go (x:xs) (y:ys)
        | x == y = let (  included, excluded)     = go xs ys
                   in  (x:included, excluded)
```

Then comes the interesting part! What I essentially want to know is if the first element of one of the lists does *not* exist in the second list – in that case I should add it to the excluded lists and then continue the search.

```hs
        | x < y  = let (included, (  xex,   yex)) = go xs (y:ys)
                   in  (included, (x:xex,   yex))
        | y < x  = let (included, (  xex,   yex)) = go (x:xs) ys
                   in  (included, (  xex, y:yex))
```

And this is actually it. It seems to work for at least the example you gave.

```hs
> let (matched, unmatched) = overlap x y
> matched
[2,2,3]
> unmatched
([1,3],[4,4,5])
```

Comment: Looks like you solved the OPs dilemma by always removing the first element (instead of searching for an element to put into `matched`, you always pick the first and then determine where it should go). I think your algorithm actually works if it isn't sorted because you always look through the rest of the list if the first elements don't match. I would say that it's _faster_ if you sort first because you could change `notElem` to be a bit more efficient to take advantage of the sorting.

Comment: @roliu the difficulty without sorting is that you get a fourth case in the recursive case; something needs to happen if either `x` or `y` exists further down in the list. I don't know of a sensible way to take care of that – the easiest way out I could find was to just move those elements further back the list, and thus propagate them backward until you can handle them. The code gets a little uglier, though.

Comment: Since you have the lists sorted, I think you could replace `notElem` with something like `x < y`.

Comment: @kqr Ah you're right. Ultimately if such a solution exists, I think sorting would actually be faster because of the optimization svick mentioned (I called it "chang[ing] `notElem` to be a bit more efficient to take advantage of the sorting"). But it's an interesting problem of how to do it... I guess I'd have a function called `match` which returned the list with the match removed? So you'd need to recursively search the list and pass the "processed" part and the "unprocessed part". Not _too_ ugly but at least _as_ ugly as sorting which is more efficient anyways...

Comment: @svick absolutely! Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're describing [multiset (bag)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) and its operations.

If you use the appropriate data structures, operations are very easy to implement:

```
// Assume that X, Y are initialized bags
let matches = X.IntersectWith(Y)
let x = X.Difference(Y)
let y = Y.Difference(X)
```

There's no built-in Bag collection in .NET framework. You could use Power Collection library including [Bag class](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#71500) where the above function signature is taken.

**UPDATE:**

You can represent a bag by a *weakly ascending list*. Here is an *improved* version of @kqr's answer in F# syntax:

```
let overlap xs ys =
    let rec loop (matches, ins, outs) xs ys =
        match xs, ys with
        // found a match
        | x::xs', y::ys' when x = y -> loop (x::matches, ins, outs) xs' ys'
        // `x` is smaller than every element in `ys`, put `x` into `ins`
        | x::xs', y::ys' when x < y -> loop (matches, x::ins, outs) xs' ys
        // `y` is smaller than every element in `xs`, put `y` into `outs`
        | x::xs', y::ys' -> loop (matches, ins, y::outs) xs ys'
        // copy remaining elements in `xs` to `ins`
        | x::xs', [] -> loop (matches, x::ins, outs) xs' ys
        // copy remaining elements in `ys` to `outs`
        | [], y::ys' -> loop (matches, ins, y::outs) xs ys'
        | [], [] -> (List.rev matches, List.rev ins, List.rev outs)
    loop ([], [], []) (List.sort xs) (List.sort ys)
```

After two calls to `List.sort`, which are probably `O(nlogn)`, finding matches is linear to the sum of the lengths of two lists.

If you need a quick-and-dirty bag module, I would suggest a module signature like this:

```
type Bag<'T> = Bag of 'T list

module Bag =
    val count : 'T -> Bag<'T> -> int
    val insert : 'T -> Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T>
    val intersect : Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T>
    val union : Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T>
    val difference : Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T> -> Bag<'T>
```

Comment: That's helpful. I initially looked at sets, which implement the operations I care about, except that they don't handle duplicates. I suspected I was missing the right data structure - glad to know it has a name! And of course, now the next question for me is to look at how a bag is implemented...